# Post Title Not showing up

Tags: php, wp-query, attachments

Hi i'm using this code to call post from a certain category

```
<?php
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'category_name' => 'photos-bet-awards-2013-2',
            'orderby' => 'date',
        ));
// The Loop!
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
?>
<?php
while ($queryObject->have_posts()){
    $queryObject->the_post();
    ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('betphumbs'); ?>
                    </a>

             <?php  
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'offset' => 0,
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'asc',
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    if(wp_attachment_is_image( $attachment->ID )) {
    echo '<a href="'. get_attachment_link($attachment->ID) . '"><?php the_title(); ?>    </a>';
    break;
 }
}
}

?>


<span class="entry-date"><font color="#999999">
<?php
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID));
$nbImg = count($attachments);
echo ''.$nbImg.' photos.';
?><br><b> <?php the_time('m/d/y \a\t g:ia') ?></b></font></span>

<?php
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Now the problem that I am having is the for some reason `<?php the_title(); ?>` isn't grabbing the post title **how can i fix this?**

Comment: looks like a syntax error; look closely at the syntax highlighting in your code above; the `echo` string is not terminated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
$first_attachment = reset($attachments); 
$first_attachment_id = $first_attachment->ID;
$first_attachment_title = $first_attachment->post_title;
```

Below:

```
$nbImg = count($attachments);
```

Now you are able to return the link with:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_link( $first_attachment_id, '' , true, false, $first_attachment_title );
```

If you need a sort of custom link markup, you can have a look at the related functions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link

**Edit:**

There is no need to get the attachements twice, as far as I see you only need to know how many attachements you have and the URL to the first attachement. So you could replace:

```
<?php  
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'offset' => 0,
'orderby' => 'menu_order',

...

break;
 }
}
}

?>
```

With:

```
<?php
$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID));
$nbImg = count($attachments);
$first_attachment = reset($attachments); 
$first_attachment_id = $first_attachment->ID;
$first_attachment_title = $first_attachment->post_title;
?>
```

After that, you can place your link:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_link( $first_attachment_id, '' , true, false, $first_attachment_title ); ?>
```

Comment: What exactly are you showing me? Will this allow the title of the post to appear, because right now the only thing i need is the post title to appear and that's not showing up. The attachment count code doesn't have anything to do with the code for the title of the post lol @rfrq

Comment: You edited your question just a few minutes before my answer. Now you would have to replace `<?php the_title(); ?>` with `' . $attachment->post_tilte . '` . Or you try my edited answer.

Comment: how do i change this `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_link( $first_attachment_id, '' , true, false, $first_attachment_title ); ?>` to grab the post title instead of the attachment title @rfrq

Comment: Just change `$first_attachment_title` to `get_the_title()` .

Comment: I did that but it's still showing the attachment title instead of the title of the post the attachment is attached to @rfrq

Comment: do you have another solutions @rfrq